# The quadrilateral X has vertices at A = (0,1), B= (2,0), C=(6,1), and D= (6,4). How would you fill up the plane with the shape X as much as possible?

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

So I have the following image of a shape X:
[image]

It's asking how to fill the plane with as much shape X as possible. I'm guessing it's asking me how to align it so that there is least amount of free space. Any way to figure that out?

Answer (score 1):

Glue a mirrored copy of the quadrilateral along $AD$. You will obtain a convex hexagon  which is symmetric with respect to the point $(3,5/2)$. This hexagon tessellates the plane (see [LINK](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HexagonTiling.html)).

P.S. Any quadrilateral can tile the plane:
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AnyQuadrilateralCanTile/

Comment: Can any (convex) quadrilateral be tessellated this way?

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, because all interior angles sum up to 360. In the tessellation, at each meeting point we will have all the  four interior angles (of four different quadrilaterals).

Comment: Wow that's crazy. So just add a mirrored image to the trapezoid, to turn the shape into a hexagon, then shape it up like a honeycomb.

Comment: Did not see it before. Can you now proceed with the tiling as suggested by Robert Z?